# What are the odds of a certain event happening?

Tags: probability

12 teams in my fantasy league. 5 teams owners live in queens, 7 do not. Each week 1 team plays another team (6 matchups per week)

What are the chances that in any given week, none of the matchups are between two Queens teams? I.e. there are 0 inter-queens matchups.

Comment: what are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The **total space** is where six pairs are selected from twelve teams (and order of grouping is unimportant).

The **favoured space** is where each of the five special teams are matched with one of the seven other teams, and the remaining two teams form a pair.

Now, can you count the ways?